# Flink - multiple job managers in jobmanager.rpc.address

Tags: apache-flink

I'm trying to configure Flink with two job managers for HA. Should I specify both of them in flink-conf.yaml / jobmanager.rpc.address ?
If yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to. In HA mode the rpc.address is chosen automatically by default. Have a look at [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/setup/jobmanager_high_availability.html#masters-file-masters).

> By default, the job manager will pick a random port for inter process
>   communication. You can change this via the
>   high-availability.jobmanager.port key. This key accepts single ports
>   (e.g. 50010), ranges (50000-50025), or a combination of both
>   (50010,50011,50020-50025,50050-50075).